# Sort map in descending order java8

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, java-8

```
private static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V>
    sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
    {
        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>> st = map.entrySet().stream();

        st.sorted( Map.Entry.comparingByValue() )
                .forEachOrdered( e -> result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()) );

        return result;
    }
```

This is an example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) post. It works. the problem is that it sorts in ascending order. How can I change it to descending ?

I can do that like this:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V>
sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
{
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );//change o1 with o2
        }
    } );

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
    {
        result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can do that by changing order i this line: `return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );` But I would like to try with lambda expr.

Comment: before we answer that, [what have you tried, yourself](/help/how-to-ask)? where have you looked to find the answer, what have you tinkered with, have you looked up the documentation for the API calls you see in this code, etc?

Comment: By the way, do not use `.forEach/.forEachOrdered` for adding entries to the map, just use collect with `Collectors.toMap` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Comparator`'s default method `reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) to reverse the sense of comparisons to sort it descending.

The type inference seems to be a little off here, but supplying explicit type arguments to `comparingByValue()` fixes the issue.

```
st.sorted( Map.Entry.<K, V>comparingByValue().reversed() )
       .forEachOrdered(e -> result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the already provided comparator and multiply the compareTo return-value by -1 or simply swap the arguments (to account for the corner cases).

```
(a,b)-->{comparingByValue().compareTo(b,a)}
```

Comment: Why not just `compareTo(b, a)`?

Comment: Mathematically both things are equivalent, performance wise your version is faster. In the end I don't think it matters.

Comment: Not quite equivalent: the comparator might return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to indicate that `a < b`.